# Android - Set notification to never go away

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I have this code that works great:

```
Notification n = builder.build();
n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

But when I restart the phone, the notification goes away. Is there any flag that make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print notification when the device boots up, you can create a receiver that is invoked when the system boot is completed, for this, first create a receiver,

```
public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
        Log.d("BOOT COMPLETE","SERVICE CALLED>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        //use your code here to print notifications

    }
}
```

This receiver is invoked when the system boot is completed. You can also call a service from the onReceive method of receiver to print the notification.

Also you must define the following regularities in your manifest file,

First define permission for getting BOOT_COMPLETION intent,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Then define your receiver also,

```
 <receiver android:name=".MyReciever" 
             android:enabled="true" 
             android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't think that is possible.

You could have a **[service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)** that runs at start-up to to bring up that notification again. Notifications otherwise do not persist across reboots.

Comment: Let's say the text in the notification was saved as a variable, how would it know that text? Would I have to save the message into a database?

Comment: A database would be overkill for a notification. You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: A database is just one method of persistent storage, but yes, you would need to save it somehow.

Comment: Gotcha. But a service would have to start to bring up those notifications though... right?

Comment: Yes. You can get it to load when Boot is complete. There is a detailed answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android) that can help you do that.

Comment: @EGHDK you don't need a service, just set the notification after receiving the broadcast.

Comment: @vikki what do you mean by broadcast?

Comment: @EGHDK a broadcast is a message sent out when an event occurs. The message is received by a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). in the link posted by Cthulhu in his comment above mine, in the accepted answer a broadcastReceiver is created and registered to be informed when android boots up, in the answer, a service is created when that message is received, for you, you shouldn't start a service, just create the notification there